# How to use members of temporary instance in C++?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, temporary, method-chaining

I have an object A with copy constructor and assignment operator which has a member QVector. I use it that way:

```
QVector<B*> x = GetA().GetVector();
x.at(0)->doSomething();
```

Now I want to do something with all the B's in the vector but because from *GetA()* I only got a temporary copy, the pointers got deleted already. Is there a different way then doing something like

```
A a = GetA();
QVector<B*> x = a.GetVector();
x.at(0)->doSomething();
```

Is this a problem of my copy constructor or anything else I can fix in the implementation of the copy constructor or the assignment operator?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a problem of your copy constructor, but of course this is "something else".

You should return a vector of [shared pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) from `GetVector()` function, because what you really want is to shared ownership on `B*` objects which are in this vector between some object `A` and your code presented in this question.

**[UPDATE]**

That method chaining: `GetA().GetVector().at(0)->doSomething();` will work, because it is guaranteed by C++ std that until sequential point (`;` in this case) all temporaries exist.

If you split this into many lines, as in your example then you should keep the result of `GetA()` in some named variable.

Some other way is to use extra function, using `GetA()` as argument (very similar to your own solution):

```
void foo(const A& a)
{
   QVector<B*> x = a.GetVector();
   x.at(0)->doSomething();
}

foo(GetA());
```

Or even:

```
void foo(const QVector<B*>& x)
{
   x.at(0)->doSomething();
}

foo(GetA().GetVector());
```

Or even in C++11, use lambda expression:

```
int main() {
  auto foo = [](const QVector<B*>& x)
    {
       x.at(0)->doSomething();
    };
    foo(GetA().GetVector());
}
```

Comment: @user1760653 I am not sure what you mean by "method chaining" here. If you want to share responsibility over some object (in your case of class B) then one of the ways if to use shared_ptr. You can also return copies of `B` objects, I mean `QVector<B> x = a.GetVector();` if this solution is suitable for you. What you cannot is to use pointer to already deleted objects.

Comment: It is obvious that I cannot use deleted pointers. ;)
With method chaining I mean GetA().GetVector(). The question is if GetVector can stay a simple getter (just returning the member and no copy operations or anything else) or if I can force the caller to keep a copy of A.